# How to install & upgrade my Video Driver

Tags: 12.04, drivers, intel-graphics

One helpful folk during  troubleshooting on VirtualBox told me that my graphic driver is too old.

```
00:00:02.714 OpenGL Info: Render SPU: GL_VENDOR:   Tungsten Graphics, Inc
00:00:02.714 OpenGL Info: Render SPU: GL_RENDERER: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset x86/MMX/SSE2
00:00:02.714 OpenGL Info: Render SPU: GL_VERSION:  2.1 Mesa 8.0.2
```

Trying to solve  the problem, I referred [this link](http://intellinuxgraphics.org/2012.02.html).

But now I don't know how to proceed and what to download and how to install the latest driver for my video card.

The graphic card was included   in the purchase, so i think it is an integrated one.

For more info here is my pci Info generated by Hardinfo:

```
PCI Devices
Host bridge Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
VGA compatible controller   Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Display controller  Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
USB controller  Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
USB controller  Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
USB controller  Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
USB controller  Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Audio device    Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
PCI bridge  Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
PCI bridge  Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
PCI bridge  Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
PCI bridge  Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
PCI bridge  Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
USB controller  Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
USB controller  Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
USB controller  Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
USB controller  Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
PCI bridge  Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
ISA bridge  Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
SATA controller Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
SMBus   Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
Ethernet controller Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
Network controller  Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
SD Host controller  Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller (rev 01)
System peripheral   Ricoh Co Ltd Memory Stick Host Controller (rev 01)
FireWire (IEEE 1394)    Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 PCIe IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
```

Comment: You should publish more information like if the your video is integrated and what model it is.

Comment: I thought "Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset x86/MMX/SSE2" is the model identity. If not how could i identify the same ?

Comment: **WHY** do you think you need to upgrade the driver -- what problems is it causing? The information you posted shows that the graphics driver is current and functional. (`Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset x86/MMX/SSE2`). And where does Virtualbox come in????

Comment: Your **want** , to upgrade to newer version is your problem or you want to install video driver (which seems to be  already installed).

Comment: @izx It is the problem with aero of win7 in virtualbox. & the guy from VBOX forum told me the driver need to be updated .
Quoting the three line i gave in first codes.

Comment: @tijybba want to upgrade to the letest version, I suppose so .

Comment: Did you find out that a newer version is available or guessed, or is it that a newer graphics driver for Windows is arrived  which is why you want the same for Ubuntu.If it is so,then i would like to add that , Newer (On-board) drivers are installed on a Kernel Upgrade / update.. You don't need to worry for newer updates as far as Onboard Graphic is concerned since it is updated more often than windows and plus supports better stability .And how it is done in kernel take a look [here](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/What-s-new-in-Linux-3-4-1575313.html), just an eaxmple.

Comment: Since the problem is with virtualbox you did install VirtualBox Guest Additions  didnt you?

Comment: To me this sounds like a bad advice. My laptop has the same GPU and the same drivers as yours, yet Aero works fine for me with VirtualBox. Make sure the Guest Additionsn for your guest OS (Win vista/7) are installed.

Answer (score 1):

You have the most current stable driver version - mesa 8.0 is part of the latest stable graphics stack, so probably your Intel driver version is 2.17. Upgrading the driver usually involves upgrading the entire stack, from the kernel to the X server. Driver-only upgrades are possible, but you don't get the full benefits of the upgrade since some improvements depend on changes to a different part of the stack.

First of all, I would discourage upgrading if there is no good reason to do so. Your driver version is current, so you may want to double-check with this person in the forum in case they made a mistake or meant something else. There are very good reasons why each Ubuntu release sticks to a given version of its packages instead of constantly releasing them in the archives, the relevant point being that you get a new well-tested software stack every 6 months, which in my opinion strikes excellent balance between stability and how long you have to wait for new software versions.

Now if you are absolutely sure you want to upgrade your graphics stack, visit:

1. [This PPA](https://launchpad.net/~glasen/+archive/intel-driver) which will upgrade your driver, bringing your Intel driver from the 2.17 version in precise to 2.19
2. [The xorg-edgers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) which will upgrade your entire graphics stack, including the 2.19 Intel driver, plus mesa 8.1, linux 3.5 and a large number of other packages

More importantly, be aware of the following:

1. PPAs can be uninstalled with [ppa-purge](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ppa-purge)
2. If your installation is 64-bit, bear in mind that `ppa-purge` does not get along well with precise's multiarch (see note at top of xorg-edgers PPA, which states the situation a bit more dramatically), and the uninstallation of a PPA may force you to uninstall a bunch of unrelated i386 packages

Comment: Thank you very much, Gonna study a bit & if i got them well then gonna give them a try.

Comment: Please consider reading my other comment before attempting to make such profound changes to your system.