# OpenGlES code runs gives error: X Error of failed request: BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)

Tags: drivers, xorg, intel, fglrx

I am using a Intel GMA 4500 on my Dell Vostro 1015. Recently migrated to Ubuntu 12.04.
The code compiles successfully but on running gives the above error.

After perusing through some more posts, I installed fglrx as well. After that, the error which I get is: libEGL warning: failed to create a pipe screen for i965
At this stage glxinfo and glxgears perform as they should.

When i did a system reboot, all these seem to be gone. I get the following message when I try to run my program, or use any of the above( fglrx, glxinfo, glxgears):

```
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  136 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  20
  Current serial number in output stream:  20
```

I did, went through some other posts as well but they were more AMD oriented and I could not get it how could they be useful for my Intel drivers, if possible.

Comment: I have described the whole process so far. The details of my system is listed in first couple of lines and current problem in the main question. Rest is some measures which i have taken so far

Comment: This post solved my problem:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/154833/how-to-install-upgrade-my-video-driver